# Condition with one to many relation emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am having two table one is post and other is comment. I have a page with only post list, I need to display a icon for post if it contains comments.

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    user_name: DS.attr('string'),
    user_id: DS.attr('number'),
    comment: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    user_id: DS.attr('number'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment',{embedded:true}),
```

This is a sample handlebar

```
1. testpost     <show icon only if comment not empty>
```

Comment: sorry, I did an edit on the answer after you read it, have another look please for the more correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you could create a `computed property` which listens to your comments property if it has at least the `firstObject` set, this would mean that there are comments, something like this:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  user_id: DS.attr('number'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment',{embedded:true}),
  hasComments: function() {
    var commentsLength = this.get('comments.length');
    return (commentsLength > 0);
  }.property('comments.firstObject')
});
```

And then in your template you add a `if` helper to listen to the `hasComments` computed property, this will show the content between the `if` helper if `post.hasComments` returns true, this would be when `(commentsLength > 0)` evaluates to `true`:

```
1. testpost {{#if post.hasComments}}<show icon>{{/if}}
```

### **EDIT**

See here for a working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aximug/3/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its not showing anything. I am new to ember so what does this mean `return (commentsLength > 0)`

Comment: @RelicSet, see my edited answer I've added a demo, and as for `return (commentsLength > 0)` this is nothing ember related, in the line above we get the length of the comments array and if it's `greater 0` we return true.